# How to map to an existing Hibernate model using jOOQ fetchInto()?

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, jooq

I'm trying to use the jOOQ `fetchInto()` method to map to an existing Hibernate model `Organization` (class and its inheritances are below).

```
Organization organization = jooq().select().from(ORGANIZATION).fetchOne().into(Organization.class);
```

The problem I have is that I can't really understand what happens in [DefaultRecordMapper](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) as I feel I'm not entirely familiar with all the terms that are used. I'm trying to figure out how it applies to the Hibernate classes that are in my codebase.

So far what I've tried:

- Use the jOOQ generated POJO's to see if it retrieves and maps the data at all (works).
- Add a constructor, getters and setters to the `Organization` Hibernate model.
- Add `@Column` annotation to `name` in the `Organization` Hibernate model.

What works:

- `id` field gets mapped correctly.

What doesn't work:

- `name` field doesn't get mapped (`null`).
- `createdAt` and `modifiedAt` fields do not get mapped (`null`).

My question is: Is there something I am overlooking with the mapping and what are the things I should look at concerning the classes, fields, constructors and annotations with Hibernate models? I want to eventually map all the Hibernate models in the codebase and use `fetchInto` to do that.

Thanks! :)

```
@Entity
public class Organization extends BaseModel {
  @Required public String name;

  //... a lot of other code
}
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseModel extends Model {
  /** The datetime this entity was first saved. Automatically set by a JPA prePersist */
  @NoBinding
  @Column
  @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
  public DateTime createdAt;

  /** The datetime this entity was last modified. Automatically set by a JPA preUpdate */
  @NoBinding
  @Column
  @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
  public DateTime modifiedAt;

  //...
}
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Model extends GenericModel { // Both Model and GenericModel are from the Play Framework
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public Model() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public Object _key() {
        return this.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to map to Hibernate entities? Backwards compatibility? A faster migration path? Or because you want to persist changes again through the entity manager?

Comment: So basically backwards compatibility for the enormous amount of methods that exist on the models. So your initial answer with the link is probably my best bet for now to solve this problem.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm assuming those methods contain business logic. I think that's not what's recommended with JPA as well, so perhaps as a first refactoring step, you could move those out of the entitites, independently of using jOOQ? I've updated my answer with a hint on what didn't work on the `name` column.

Comment: Yes, lots of business logic. For now its using jOOQ by translating existing string queries to jOOQ queries, but letting it be executed by Hibernate. Further refactoring steps should logically follow. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jOOQ doesn't support all the many JPA and Hibernate specific annotations. Historically, it supported a few JPA annotations (because why not), but full interop would be excessive and investing product development time in the wrong places. jOOQ is by no means a JPA implementation.

#### Step 0: Why didn't (some) of the mappings work?

As mentioned before, not all JPA specification is implemented. For example, a known issue is that `@Column` annotations are still mandatory in jOOQ:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4586

There might be other such limitations, which could be considered bugs. Feel free to report them if you want to continue down this path: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

But things like `@MappedSuperclass` or `@Type` are unlikely to ever be supported by jOOQ.

#### Step 1: Do you really need it?

You've decided to create and run your query with jOOQ. I imagine your *actual* query is much more complex than what you're showing, because for that particular query, you don't need jOOQ.

Do you really *need to* map to Hibernate entities? Because even when you use Hibernate, the recommended approach is to use entities *only* when you're going to modify them and store the delta back to the database. If that's the case, see step 2 below. If it's not the case, why not use jOOQ's own mapping functionality to work with any style of jOOQ supported POJO?

#### Step 2: Use Hibernate to execute the jOOQ query

If you're using jOOQ only to build a rather complex SQL query and you *need* Hibernate entities as a result, then [use Hibernate to execute the jOOQ query as documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/alternative-execution-models/using-jooq-with-jpa/using-jooq-with-jpa-entities/). A small utility should be enough:

```java
public static <E> List<E> nativeQuery(EntityManager em, org.jooq.Query query, Class<E> type) {
    Query result = em.createNativeQuery(query.getSQL(), type);

    List<Object> values = query.getBindValues();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
        result.setParameter(i + 1, values.get(i));

    return result.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Indeed, the SQL queries are much more complicated (as are the models). I wanted a way to map them to the existing models with jOOQ so I can use the full models and its methods so I don't have to change the data structures on multiple layers of the application (skinny controller, fat models). So I really need the Hibernate entities. But I also wanted to remove the dependency on Hibernate to execute the query, but that apparently doesn't seem possible now unless I change entire layers of the application. Maybe something I'm going to do later, haha.

Comment: @Bram: Famous "later" :) Well, using Hibernate to execute your queries will be the least intrusive change for now. You don't have to migrate everything in a single go.

Comment: Haha, yea I'll be going for that least intrusive path for now. Step by step I'll get jOOQ more into the codebase hopefully. Beautiful library!